# Unsupported operand type error while using class variable and class method for counting instance creation

Tags: python-3.x

I defined my class variable "count_instance", so as to count the number of instances created with my class "Person". After initialization, I wrote the command "Person.count_instance +=1". This is so that my count_instance will increase by 1 with each new instance creation.

But when I am creating my instances (object) of my class it results in an error saying- "unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'".

Can someone please help me why is this happening? and How to fix this. I am using python 3.6

I tried to check the semantic and syntactic errors. But I couldn't fix this problem.

```py
    class Person:
        count_instance = 0
        def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age): # These are attributes in the bracket and init is the initialization method.
    #Instance Variable declaration
            Person.count_instance +=1
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.Last_name = last_name
            self.age = age
        @classmethod
        def count_instance(cls):
            return f"You have created {cls.count_instance} of Person Class"

        def full_name(self):
            return(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")

        def is_above_18(self):
            return self.age>18

    #Creating the instances
    p1 = Person("Sara", "Kat", 18)
    p2 = Person("Pankaj", "Mishra", 26)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeFgJ.png)
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'**

Comment: Name your variable differently from the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count_instance` is both a variable and a method in your code. Use unique names for both. For instance by changing the method to `print_count_instance`:

```
class Person:
    count_instance = 0
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age): # These are attributes in the bracket and init is the initialization method.
#Instance Variable declaration
        Person.count_instance +=1
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.Last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
    @classmethod
    def print_count_instance(cls):
        return f"You have created {cls.count_instance} of Person Class"

    def full_name(self):
        return(f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}")

    def is_above_18(self):
        return self.age>18

#Creating the instances
p1 = Person("Sara", "Kat", 18)
p2 = Person("Pankaj", "Mishra", 26)

p1.print_count_instance()
```